# Store iPhone Location as NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, location

I am fairly new to `Objective-c` & currently building my first App. I am trying to output an iPhones location to a string to be used in a `JSON` request.

I have the request built but I am unsure how to get the iPhones location, let alone into a string & the apple Documentation i am finding difficult to follow.

How can I do this?

Edit: I've seen how to implement location like so:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
CLLocationDegrees latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
CLLocationDegrees longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
}
```

However i am unsure where to put this, this isn't an object is it?

I don't need to initialize it?

I tried editing this to return the newLocation as a stirng instead of void, but how do I call it?

What input do I need into (`CLLocationManager` *)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CLLocationManager` class allow you to track your current location.

If you want use it to find your location, that's what you need to do :

```
// Create an instance of CLLocationManager class :
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

// Set the delegate of your instance :
locationManager.delegate = self; // Set your controller as a <CLLocationManagerDelegate>.

// Now update your location :
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Now, everytime a `CLLocationManager` instance did update, the delegate method is called :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations;
```

Which means everytime your `locationManager` update its location, this method is called.

Now you can overwrite the method by adding in your .m file :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    // Do whatever you want here
}
```

For example, if you want to store your current coordinates you can do :

**Declare in the .h :**

```
float latitude;
float longitude;
```

**Then complete the delegate method (write this in .m) :**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    latitude = [manager location].coordinate.latitude;
    longitude = [manager location].coordinate.longitude;
}
```

Now you can store your values in NSString like @amar answered.

I have edited this answer like 6 times so I hope this will answer your question and help you :D.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",<your float>];`

Comment: Edited question to include more detail on problem

Comment: ... all you need is `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",<your float>];`, all you need is `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",<your float>];`, `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",<your float>];`, `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",<your float>];` [is all you need.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLGWyfGk_LU)